# Laravel usando AJAX error 404 en peticion

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax

Tengo un problema con una peticion ajax en laravel 8, la idea es extraer unos simples datos, pero al momento de realizar la peticion me marca error 404

Esta es la peticion que estoy realizando

```
$.ajax({
            url :'excursiones/reserva/',
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            data :{
                'value': value

            },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
```

Asi esta declarado mi api routes

```
Route::get('excursiones/reserva/{titulo}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PruebaController@excursiones');
```

Y este es el resultado que me salta desde la web
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si realizo la peticion directamente desde la ruta declarada si me muestra la informacion, pero esa no es la idea, creo que el problema se encuentra dentro de la ruta declarada en ajax pero no logro dar con el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el siguiente código indicas que la url contendrá un titulo

```php
 Route::get('excursiones/reserva/{titulo}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PruebaController@excursiones');
```

y en la imagen puedes ver que estas ingresando un parámetro mediante url, normalmente esta forma de pasar valores mediante url se utiliza en peticiones **POST**.

Lo que tienes que hacer es indicar el titulo despues de *..reserva/*  en este caso seria *excursiones/reserva/titulo*

```js
$.ajax({
            url :`excursiones/reserva/${value}`,
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            data :{
            },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
```